# SQL server management studio Relationships connection

Tags: ssms, relationship, erd

In databases you can define relationships between tables. But what exactly is the use, besides documentation, of making these relationships explicit in a diagram (for example by connecting the keys in SQL server management studio)?

Does it give you any advantage in writing SQL statements? Computation time? Memory usage? Usually you "repeat" the relationship in the join statement. I have the feeling I'm missing something trivial.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking what the use is of the "New Database Diagram" seen when right clicking the Database Diagrams node in the Object Explorer? What was the purpose of the biggest database you've ever worked on? How many tables did it have? How many foreign key relationships?

Answer (score 0):

From [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/create-a-new-database-diagram-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15)

> You can use Object Explorer to create new database diagrams. Database diagrams graphically show the structure of the database. Using database diagrams you can create and modify tables, columns, relationships, and keys. Additionally, you can modify indexes and constraints.

You asked:

> Does it give you any advantage in writing SQL statements?

They can tell you how the datase is structured. That's usually pretty key to understanding it, and reading all the FKs into your head and remembering which table relates to what can be quite the puzzle and even then not actually relate to how the data is used and related in-application

> Computation time?

Not quite sure what this means, but the presence or absence of a database diagram won't impact the amount of time your SQL Server spends planning or executing queries

> Memory usage?

Not really

> Usually you "repeat" the relationship in the join statement

Sometimes; there are ways of joining data without using joins, and presence or absence of FKs or database diagrams have nothing to do with SQLS ability to join data

It might be best to think of DB Diagrams as a visual design aid and tool